# How to edit Jetstream error messages in Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, passwords, laravel-8, laravel-jetstream

I am using Jetstream in Laravel for user registration and login, I am identifying several error messages and I want to change them, the message: "The password must be at least 8 characters." and the other, I can't find where they are located, thanks

I have tried to look for error messages within the structure in Laravel, I changed some, however, these specific ones I cannot find their origin

Error messages that I want to change:

[image: error message]

Comment: All error messages (Laravel defaults, not plugins) are located in the `validation.php` file, where you have translations. If you are literally looking for the error, you will never find it, because `8` is a placeholder, it is a validation rule message... You can see it [here](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/78ad150a947f6677d9cb4e3eb9a257d312fe14c3/resources/lang/en/validation.php#L96). I do not think you can change the messages without changing them on the file I mentioned, but have in mind that changing that rule message is going to change for any rule that uses it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For laravel jetstream, you can go to `app/Actions/Fortify/CreateNewUser.php` file

and on `create(array $input)` method change the validator to like below

```php
Validator::make($input, [
    'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
    'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
    'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
    'terms' => Jetstream::hasTermsAndPrivacyPolicyFeature() ? ['accepted', 'required'] : '',
],
[
    'password.confirmed'=>"The :attribute  confirmation does not match, bro...", // this is your custom message
    'password.min'=>'The :attribute length minimum is :min characters.', // this is your custom message
]
)->validate();
```

you can use `password.confirmed` to only apply on password field only or just `confirmed` to apply on other fields also.

You can check below documentation link for more details:

https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#manual-customizing-the-error-messages

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, the password.confirmed part worked, however, the password.min part did not change the message, do you know what the correct function name would be?